# Tense of て clauses

Tags: grammar, translation, て-form

I answered a question a while back where I translated the following:

> ＪＲ東日本は、新幹線で無線のＬＡＮのサービスを始めて、無料でインターネットが利用できるようにすることにしました
>
> JR East-Japan is beginning wireless LAN service on the shinkansen and decided to make it so that passengers are able to use the internet for free. (This could obviously be worded better in English).

While reviewing, I started wondering if I had made an error in the tense of 始めて.  **In the above sentence, absent of context, is the sequence of actions clear?**

In other words, I am wondering which of the following is a more accurate understanding (not translation):

1. JR Higashi Nihon began offering wireless service and then decided to make it free.
2. JR Higashi Nihon began offering wireless service and it was free from the beginning.
3. JR Higashi Nihon started installing the necessary equipment for wireless service and then decided to make it free. (This is how I interpret my translation which is why I am so hesitant.)

Original if useful: [What do で and ように express here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54580/what-do-%e3%81%a7-and-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab-express-here/54581#54581)

Comment: It might have been free from the beginning but their original intent was not to make it free, but at some point they decided to work towards making it free. At least, this is how I understand it. Not sure how accurate my translation is, but I would go with, "JR Higashi Nihon began offering Wi-Fi and was (eventually) able to make it free to use... (for anyone with an email address)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without taking any background knowledge into consideration, people usually read this like ようにすることにしました is applied to 「新幹線で無線のＬＡＮのサービスを始めて、無料でインターネットが利用できる」 as a whole (i.e., "JR East decided to start wireless LAN service and enable ...").

(In fact, this article is confusing because paid wireless LAN service has been available for Tokaido Shinkansen users for a long time. [The original news](https://response.jp/article/2017/11/07/302197.html) is about JR East's other Shinkansen lines which have had no wireless LAN service whatsoever.)