# The use of で and に with 座る

Tags: particle-に, particle-で, に-and-で

I came across this example in Genki I

> .....まどの近く**に**座っています

And I was wondering about the use of に here and if we can replace it with で to make

> ......まどの近く**で**座っています

Is it correct? Please explain if possible. And thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4594/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2197/9831

Answer (score 9):

For 座る, the place where (or object on which) one sits is marked with に. I would say that

- ～の近くで座る is **unnatural**
- ～の近くに座る is **natural**.

#### Explanation

Verbs which are *inherently linked to a location* — such as 行く, 住む, いる, etc. — have this location marked by **に**.

Verbs for which the location is only circumstantial (i.e. additional information) — such as 食べる, 遊ぶ, 勉強する, etc. — have this location marked by **で**.

#### Numerical evidence

The Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese (BCCWJ) contains no instances of 近くで＋座る. It does contain some instances of で＋座る, but none of these use で to mark the location where the sitting takes place...

---

#### Case study 寝る

One interesting verb to look at for the difference between に and で is 寝る. The numbers in BCCWJ are ambiguous:

- に＋寝る `1,337 results`
- で＋寝る `1,222 results`

However, 寝る has two common meanings

1. 横たわる *to lie down*
2. 眠る *to sleep*

and the choice between に and で is not as ambiguous as the rough numbers would suggest. For 寝る "to sleep", the location is circumstantial/additional information and should be marked with で; for 寝る "to lie down", the location is inherent to the meaning of the verb and should be marked with に.

> A： Cさんまだ起きている？
>   B： いや、ベンチ**で**寝ている。

Comment: Thank you a ton I finally get it.  And sorry this is such a late reply for some reason i wasnt notified on my email of it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Earthlin Not considering the original sentence i.e. not considering the use of まどの近くで座っています question laid above. I wanted to ask that, if the **question would have been what are you doing near the window** *(and not where are you)*, would the use of で in the answer 窓の近くで座っています  been grammatical? As now the focus shifted from direction (i.e. from where you are) to what are you doing (focus on action)?

Comment: or should we go by the inherent meaning of the verb i.e. positional (i.e. focus of action (i.e. (で) or inherent linkage to position (に) if the question is what are you doing near the window)?

Comment: Adding on to the numerical evidence part of it, I checked the National Institute for Japanese Language and Linguistics, Japan's directory, which consists of inter-alia sources such as; books, magazines, web pages etc. Therein I found only 461 uses with で座る out of 8,732 hits, with particle before 座る, wherein 5,400 were with に座る,. Wherein, out of those, 461 searches, 90 were 足で座る(which is an altogether different aspect of で), I also, checked out 50 more, but they were completely different uses of で, and many were remotely connected with で, Link: http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp/headword/V.00165/

Answer (score 7):

## English

> (1) 窓{まど}の近く**に**座っています。
> (2) 窓｛まど｝の近く**で**座っています。

I'll answer the question based on the explanation [here](http://blog.livedoor.jp/touxia-book/archives/5512810.html).
Both (1) and (2) are correct.
However, the nuance is slightly different.
(1) means "the place where you are sitting" is "near the window", while (2) means that the place where the act of "sitting" is done is "near the window".

The "point" of the difference between "に" and "で" is the verb that comes after each of them.

> The case particle "に" is used in the case of the verb of **existence**.
> The case particle "で" is used in the case of a verb of **action/conduct**.

Therefore, the following construction of a sentence is a principle.
"～に（…が）ある・いる"
"～で…する"

However, there are verbs in which both "に" and "で" are used as follows.

> 作{つく}る, 生｛う｝まれる, 育｛そだ｝つ, 消{き}える, 暮｛く｝らす, 建｛た｝てる, 投｛な｝げる, etc.

"座る" in the example sentence presented by the questioner is also a verb that both case particles can be used.

In the case of verbs in which both case particles can be used, "で" represents action/conduct and "に" can represent existence/place.
More strictly speaking, "に" would mean that the result of the action (the result of conduct) is realized there.

I'll show example sentences using verbs that could be attached to both case particles of "で" and "に" as follows.

新{あたら}しい施設｛しせつ｝が中国｛ちゅうごく｝のテレビ工場｛こうじょう｝**に**作｛つく｝られた。… The place where the facilities were "constructed" is in the TV factory in China.
このテレビは中国の工場**で**作られた。… The act of making "televisions" was done in China.

田舎｛いなか｝**で**暮｛く｝らす。… It is a "田舎 *countryside*" where the act of "living" is done.
田舎**に**暮らす。… The place where someone is "living" is a countryside.

森{もり}**で**家｛いえ｝を建｛た｝てた。… The act of building a house was done in the forest. There is not necessarily the house in the forest.
森**に**家を建てた。… The place where a house was built is a forest.

河原｛かわら｝**で**石｛いし｝を投｛な｝げる。… It is "河原 *riverbed*" that the act of "投げる *throwing*" a stone is done. No one knows where the stone is.
河原**に**石を投げる。… The place as the target of "throwing" a stone is "河原 *riverbed*". The stone should be on the riverbed.

彼｛かれ｝は都会｛とかい｝**で**生｛う｝まれた/育｛そだ｝った。
彼は都会**に**生まれた/育った。

彼の姿｛すがた｝は人｛ひと｝混｛ご｝み**で**消｛き｝えた。
彼の姿は人混み**に**消えた。

## 日本語

> (1) 窓の近く**に**座っています。
> (2) 窓の近く**で**座っています。

[ここ][2]の説明に基づいて回答します。

(1)、(2)ともに間違っていません。
ただし、ニュアンスが少し違います。
(1) は、「座っている」場所が「窓の近く」と言う意味で、(2) は、「座る」という行為が行われた場所が「窓の近く」という意味です。

「に」と「で」の違いの「ポイント」は、後に来る動詞です。

> - 格助詞「に」は、**存在性**の動詞の場合に使われます。
> - 格助詞「で」は、**動作・行為性**の動詞の場合に使われます。

従って、
「～に（…が）ある・いる」
「～で…する」
というのが原則です。

ただ、以下のように「に」「で」の両方が使われる動詞もあります。

> 「作る」「生まれる」「育つ」「消える」「暮らす」「建てる」「投げる」

**質問者が提示した「座る」も両方で使われる動詞に該当します。**

その場合も、「に」は存在（場所）を表し、「で」は動作（行為）を表すということができます。
もっと厳密に言えば、「に」は、動作の結果（動作・行為の結果）がそこにおいて実現していることを表す、となると思います。

「に」「で」両方の格助詞につらなる動詞を使った例文を以下に示します。

新しい施設が中国のテレビ工場**に**作られた。…施設が「作られ」てある場所が中国。
このテレビは中国の工場**で**作られた。…テレビを「作る」という行為が行われたのが中国。

田舎**で**暮らす。…「暮らす」という行為が行われているのが田舎。
田舎**に**暮らす。…「暮ら」している場所が田舎。

森**で**家を建てた。…「建て」るという行為が行われたのが森。森に家があるとは限らない。
森**に**家を建てた。…「建て」られた家のある場所が森。

河原**で**石を投げる。…「投げる」という行為が行われたのが河原。石はどこにあるか決まらない。
河原**に**石を投げる。…「投げ」た目標（対象）としての場所が河原。石は河原にあるはず。

彼は都会**で**生まれた/育った。
彼は都会**に**生まれた/育った。

彼の姿は人混み**で**消えた。
彼の姿は人混み**に**消えた。