# Location particle with 並ぶ

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-で

Why is に, rather than で, used with the verb 並ぶ, e.g.

> 入り口に並んでいる。
> I'm stood in line at the entrance.

Using the usual distinction of で marking the location where an action takes place and に marking the target of an action, I would expect to use で. Would it be wrong to use で?

Perhaps 'to stand in line' is not an accurate translation of 並ぶ. Maybe the verb has an in-built implication of movement towards the target. Any thoughts?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55342/the-use-of-%E3%81%A7-and-%E3%81%AB-with-%E5%BA%A7%E3%82%8B https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60/particles-%E3%81%AB-vs-%E3%81%A7 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/%e3%81%ab-and-%e3%81%a7-revisited

Comment: ディスニーランドに並ぶ means you have not entered Disney Land yet, whereas ディズニーランドで並ぶ means you're in a waiting line for some attraction in Disney Land.