# 近くに見える vs 近くで見える

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-と

Can someone tell me the difference please?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55342/5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following two sentences.

> 「山が近くに見えると雨の兆し」なのは何故か
> https://blog.goo.ne.jp/qq_otenki_s/e/e1b0a205b5f40b9360bd8905c3b90165

近くに brings the location (of the mountain) into focus, and it's far more common than 近くで.

> エンパイアステートビルが近くで見えるホテル
> https://4travel.jp/os_qa_each-59348.html

近くで shifts the focus to the activity (of enjoying the view).

Tofugu has an article that dives into the contrast between に and で.
https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/ni-vs-de/

Comment: so how would the meaning change, if we were to change the で into に in the "エンパイアステートビルが近くで見えるホテル"?