# Location with the verb 寝る: に or で?

Tags: particles, verbs, particle-に

As the question says. I'm aware that the use of に with verbs like 座る and 立つ is not actually "location" に, but the "target/destination" に. However with 寝る in particular, it's still very ambiguous for me, and I have seen 寝る plenty of times with both に and で.

The most recent sentence that threw me is: 「自分のベッドで寝る。」 "I sleep in my bed." Is there a reason に would be incorrect or less natural here?

Comment: Closely related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55342/1628

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ベッドに寝る sounds natural when 寝る means “to lie down”. Like 立つ and 座る, this refers to an instantaneous action, or change of state, that results in a state of you *being* at some place.

When 寝る means “to sleep”, which is a durative action, で sounds more natural.