# ここに書いた or ここで書いた?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-で

Which particle do I use to say that something is written somewhere? I googled both versions and they have a similar number of hits. Can I use both? Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The difference between に and で when focusing on location vs. action](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57182/the-difference-between-%e3%81%ab-and-%e3%81%a7-when-focusing-on-location-vs-action)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Particles: に vs. で](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60/particles-%e3%81%ab-vs-%e3%81%a7)

Answer (score 9):

There is a huge difference.

> 「ここ**に**書{か}いた」

In this phrase 「ここに」 refers to "on what object you wrote something".  It could be in a notebook, on the chalk board, on the wall, etc.

> 「ここ**で**書{か}いた」

This talks about where the act of writing took place.  In the library?  On the bus?  In a cafe?

Thus the two phrases are not interchangeable.