人 (は or で) 混んでいる?
The language learning app that I use gives the following sentence:
渋谷は人で混んでいる
From what I understand about the particles は and で, shouldn't the sentence be:
渋谷で人は混んでいる
instead?
(Something like: 渋谷で人はたくさんいる)

"From what I understand about the particles は and で, shouldn't the sentence be" Could you elaborate on that part? I wonder what example, if any, leads you to such understanding.

Well, I thought "渋谷で..." because "で" is also used as a particle to mean "at (a place)". Then, "...人は混んでいる" because it appears to be a similar construct/meaning to "...人はたくさんいる". A more correct sentence (to me) though, would be "渋谷は人が混んでいる", but I though the app may have mistakenly swapped "は" and "で" in its sentence.

Look back at the meaning of 混んでいる.  The subject of 混んでいる is the thing/place that is getting crowded.  人が混んでいる sounds almost like you're saying people are crowded?  With what?  Somehow with 人が混んでいる I get this image of a bunch of constipated people in Shibuya.  But, it is Shibuya that is crowded with people.

@A.Ellett Thanks! The explanation that it is Shibuya and not the people that is crowded (by/with) something, is very clear!

No, only 渋谷は人で混んでいる is correct, and 渋谷で人は混んでいる is wrong. This is because of 混む's lexical meaning.
混む is a verb which does not mean "to crowd" (like "People crowd in Shibuya.") but corresponds to English "to be crowded". So the location naturally stands as the subject.

渋谷は人で混んでいる
Shibuya is crowded with people.

By the way, 渋谷で人はたくさんいる, which you mentioned, is also ungrammatical, because of a specific matter with the verb いる. いる always takes location with ～に (～で is reserved for states: 冷静でいる "be in calmness" or "keep calm"). So you have to say 渋谷に人はたくさんいる.

Thanks! I looked up jisho, and saw that "で" can also mean "by/with", so "人で" fits nicely as "by people". Regarding "で" and "に"... ah, I think I do have to study the particles more. I always thought "で" usually means "AT (a place)" whereas "に" usually means "TO (a place)", hence "学校で勉強します" vs "学校に行きます".

@PieFaced This post might also be useful: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2197/7810
